# Do I Capitalize someone's role?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

Do I use capitals when referring to someone's position within an institution or company? And is it the same for all levels of employee?

i.e in the following sentence, should the words in bold be capitalized? 
[As a double check, am I right in thinking the 'Prof', being his title. should be capitalized?]

Discussion with my **head of department**, Prof. F. Bloggs, has indicated...

Cheers

Comment: There's a lot of [guidance about this available on-line](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=capitalizing+positions+or+titles&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl), although you may have to check a few different sites to get an answer to your specific example.

Comment: As an aside, this has nothing to do with grammar. There are no capital letters in speech.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, when my grandfather was training to be a gardener, he noted that the words **Head Gardener** were always pronounced with capitals.

Comment: As @ JR states, there's no dearth of guidance. Title case conventions can vary among different authors,publications, style guides...simple rule is to pick a style and be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in British English. Capitalise job titles but not roles.

The Guardian style guide says:

> **capitals**
>
> - **jobs** all lc, eg prime minister, US secretary of state, chief rabbi, editor of the Guardian.
> - **titles** cap up titles, but not job description, eg President Barack Obama (but the US president, Barack Obama, and Obama on subsequent mention); the Duke of Westminster (the duke at second mention); Pope Francis but the pope.

http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-c

The Economist style guide says:

> ***Capitals***
>
> A balance has to be struck between so many capitals that the eyes dance and so few that the reader is diverted more by our
> style than by our substance. The general rule is to dignify with
> capital letters organisations and institutions, but not people. More
> exact rules are laid out below. Even these, however, leave some
> decisions to individual judgment. If in doubt use lower case unless it
> looks absurd. And remember that “a foolish consistency is the
> hobgoblin of little minds” (Ralph Waldo Emerson).
>
> **PEOPLE**
>
> Use upper case for ranks and titles when written in conjunction with a name, but lower case when on their own. Thus **President Bush**, but the **president**; **Vice-President Cheney**, but the
> **vice-president**; **Colonel Qaddafi**, but the **colonel**; **Pope Benedict**, but
> the **pope**; **Queen Elizabeth**, but the **queen**. 
> Do not write **Prime Minister
> Blair** or **Defence Secretary Rumsfeld**; they are the **prime minister, Mr
> Blair**, and the **defence secretary, Mr Rumsfeld**. You may, however, write
> **Chancellor Schröder**. 
> All office-holders when referred to merely by
> their office, not by their name, are lower case: **the chancellor of the
> exchequer, the foreign secretary, the prime minister, the speaker, the
> treasury secretary, the president of the United States, the chairman
> of Coca-Cola.**
>
> The only exceptions are
>
> 1. a few titles that would look unduly
>    peculiar without capitals, eg, **Black Rod, Master of the Rolls,
>    Chancellor of the Duchy of Lancaster, Lord Privy Seal, Lord
>    Chancellor.**
> 2. a few exalted people, such as the **Dalai Lama** and the
>    **Aga Khan**. Also **God** and the **Prophet**.
>
> Some titles serve as names, and
> therefore have initial capitals, though they also serve as
> descriptions: **the Archbishop of Canterbury, the Emir of Kuwait, the
> Shah of Iran**. If you want to describe the office rather than the
> individual, use lower case: **The next archbishop of Canterbury will be
> a woman. Since the demise of the ninth duke, there has never been
> another duke of Portland.**

http://www.economist.com/style-guide/capitals